# Button in dialog always return null in onStart() in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-dialog

I have Dialog in Fragment. when I click on the OK button inside the dialog, I get `null object reference error`.

```kotlin
fun showDialog(){
        //get Dialog : Numbers
        val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog_b, null)
        //AlertDialog builder
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(dialogView)
        //Show Dialog
        val alertDialog = dialogBuilder.show()

        //setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        dialogView.btn_ok.setOnClickListener {

            Log.d("Clicked", et_one.text.toString())

            alertDialog.dismiss()
        }
     }
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: et_one must not be null at com.example.algorithmsapp.AlgorithmsFragments.BFragment$onStart$1$1.onClick(BFragment.kt:63)
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception error message? Are you sure et_one or et_one.text is not null?

Comment: You can rewrite your logging line as : Log.d("Clicked ${et_one?.text}") . Now, if et_one or et_one.text are null, it will not crash.

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere Log.d("Clicked ${et_one?.text}") ->D/Clicked: null

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere in XML file edittext have default value soooo why gonna be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to intialise Edittext here to fetch value from edittext. Add below line your code**

```
var et_one: EditText
var btn_ok: Button
    et_one= layoutInflateView.findViewById(R.id.et_one)
    btn_ok= layoutInflateView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok)
```

**So Your Code Look Like This:**

```
 fun showDialog(){
    //get Dialog : Numbers
    val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.dialog_b, null)
    //AlertDialog builder
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(dialogView)
    //Show Dialog
    val alertDialog = dialogBuilder.show()
    var et_one: EditText
    var btn_ok: Button

    et_one= layoutInflateView.findViewById(R.id.et_one)
    btn_ok= layoutInflateView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok)
    //setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    dialogView.btn_ok.setOnClickListener {

        Log.d("Clicked", et_one.text.toString())

        alertDialog.dismiss()
    }
 }
```